# Issue with latency in server-side blazor application

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am experiencing an inconsistent behavior in my blazor server-side application across environments. Below is my issue:

Users click a button that does some async processing. Before processing is started, I turn on "showWaitDialog" variable so that users can see a modal dialog while processing is being done. It takes at least two seconds before the modal dialog appears. This is more prominent on the server than my local host. Users are able to click the button multiple times and I want to avoid that.

Below is simplified code and I replaced my long running task with thread.sleep for illustration purposes. my long running task makes a call to database.

```
public async Task JoinRoom()
{
  _isShowWaitDialog = true;
  await Task.Delay(1);  // allow the GUI to catch up

  await DoLongWork();

  _isShowWaitDialog = false;
  await Task.Delay(1);  // allow the GUI to catch up
}

Task DoLongWork()
{
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);
   return Task.CompletedTask;
}

razor:

.
.
<ProgressMessageModal WaitDialogParameter="@_isShowWaitDialog" />
.
.
@if (SelectedRoom != null)
{
   <div class="col-sm-1">
     <div class="form-group">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" @onclick="JoinRoom">&nbsp;Join&nbsp;</button>
     </div>
   </div>
}
```

Progress modal dialog does not show until after two seconds from the time they click Join button.

On my local host it takes 1 second for the progress modal to show whereas on the server it takes 2 seconds before I can see the progress modal dialog.

I verified in IIS manager on server and Web Sockets protocol is enabled.

Any pointers? What am I missing?

Comment: await Task.Delay(1);  // allow the GUI to catch up ??? you have planned raceconditions? at least you shouldn't need to let the gui catch up.
you sure DoLongWork really runs async?

Comment: As far as I know the average delay when your app is deployed on a server should be around 150 ms~200 ms... Try to use JSInterop to display the dialog window and disable the button.

Comment: What is await Task.Delay(1); used for?

Comment: This looks like a problem with ProgressMessageModal , can you include which library that is from?

Comment: Thanks all for your pointers! @HenkHolterman I have a room selector control in razor page that executes a database query, processes ~250 records and brings the results back. This database query is getting executed total of (5) times, two times during initial load, one time after a room is selected and then two times after clicking the "join room" button. What is it getting executed two times during initial load and two times after the button is clicked? Is it due to server  rendering?!

Comment: @HenkHolterman our render mode is server prerendered. could that be the issue?